# F# - Partial application of a Int32.TryParse

Tags: .net, f#, partial-application

I was trying to do this

```
let TryParseAnyNumberStyle = Int32.TryParse(style= NumberStyles.Any, privider=CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

But the compiler complains

> The member or object constructor 'TryParse' does not take 0 argument(s). An overload was found taking 2 arguments.

The only way I could resolve it was

```
  let TryParse numStyle culture (str:string) = 
    match Int32.TryParse(str, numStyle, culture) with
        | true, v -> true, v
        | _ -> false, 0

  let TryParseAnyNumberStyle = TryParse NumberStyles.Any CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

Why does the compiler not like my initial partial application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that, since you are calling a static method, we're not talking about [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), but [overload resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). The crucial difference is that partial application requires a function with curried arguments and an arity of at least two, while overload resolution will be performed by the compiler on methods which take tupled arguments.

Here's a simple example of partial application of the F# addition operator, reducing the arity (number of curried arguments) from two to one:

```
let add = (+)
// val add : (int -> int -> int)
let add1 = (+) 1
// val add1 : (int -> int)
```

The `TryParse` method has two overloads with two and four tupled arguments, respectively.

```
public static bool TryParse(string s, out int result)
public static bool TryParse(string s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.IFormatProvider provider, out int result)
```

For the `out` parameter, a special syntactic conversion will be performed by the F# compiler, so that you actually need to provide either one or three tupled arguments for the overload to be successfully resolved. By specifying the first, string input argument, your definition will work as expected:

```
open System
open System.Globalization
let tryParseAnyNumberStyle s =
    Int32.TryParse(s, 
        style=NumberStyles.Any, 
        provider=CultureInfo.CurrentCulture )
// val tryParseAnyNumberStyle : s:string -> bool * int
```

Comment: I had to alter your answer to ```let TryParseAnyNumberStyle (s: string) = Int32.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)``` and then the compiler was happy.  Thanks for the feedback, I see where I was going wrong now.